# Changing the case of a string in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I make a lowercase string uppercase using Eclipse? I want to select a string and either uppercase it or lowercase it. Is there a shortcut for doing this?

Answer (score 378, accepted):

By default, the hotkeys:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> changes to lowercase.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> changes to UPPERCASE.

Or, on a Mac:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> changes to lowercase.

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> changes to UPPERCASE.

Comment: do you know if this can be added to the Eclipse menu, maybe under "Edit" or under "Source" ? Those hotkeys are impossible to remember.

Comment: You can use the hot key CTRL+SHIFT+L to bring up the popup that contains all the available hot-keys

Comment: The hot key "CTRL+SHIFT+L" is for "Key Assist", which is under the "Help" menu.

Comment: on a mac you can use: cmd + shift + X (+Y)

Answer (score 28):

You can see all shortcuts of eclipse by pressing:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: Once you've done this, scroll down the shortcut list and look for **To Lower Case** and **To Upper Case** to see they are **Shift+Ctrl+Y** and **Shift+Ctrl+X**, respectively.

Answer (score 20):

```
Help-> Key assist
```

You will get all of eclipse's shortcuts.

Comment: instead of going help-> key assist you can press ctrl+shift+L

Answer (score 16):

Eclipse only provides a keyboard shortcut by default. If you prefer to use the menu, you can use the free plugin [AnyEdit Tools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools), which will add some entries to the context menu to change the case of the selected text:

[image]

To install:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> : To-lower 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> : To-Upper 

In addition, in Eclipse IDE, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, then you see this list of shortcuts panel

[image]

then you can find any shortcut